King Janaka in the Vedas
As we know , King Janaka Vaideha is mentioned in ancient Vaidika texts such as Śatapatha Brāhmaṇa , Jaiminī Brāhmaṇa and the Bṛhadāraṇyaka Upaniṣad.
I thought only these 3 texts mentioned Janaka Vaideha but on some websites we find that he is also mentioned in the Taittirīya Brāhmaṇa and the Sankhayana Srauta sutra , but no verse number is given.
So , can anyone pls provide me with the verses from the Taittirīya Brāhmaṇa and the Sankhayana Srauta sutra that mention the great Videhan King Janaka.
Thanks.
